# Change entity score within a rectangular area of the player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to set an entity to have a score of one in a scoreboard system, but only when they are within a specified range of the player. I do not want to use the `r=[number]` specifier. I am trying to use x, y, z and then use dx, dy, and dz to set a very specific area. Right now I am using:

```
/execute @a[score_rightClick_min=1,score_spellActive.fire_min=1,lm=5] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @e[x=~4.5,y=~0.25,z=~-4.5,dx=-8.5,dy=-0.1,dz=8.5,team=!Players] target.fire 1
```

The only problem with this is that it doesn't get the correct radius. It only seems to give them the score if they are right next to the player.

**Part 2**:
Okay, so I am having the same issue now, but this time it is doing things outside of the range that I have specified.

```
/execute @e[score_burned_min=1,score_burnTimer_min=5] ~0.5 ~ ~-0.5 scoreboard players set @e[dx=-1,dy=0,dz=1,team=!Players] burnChained 1
```

Not really sure what is going wrong here. If anyone knows that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use relative coordinates in target selectors. You also cannot use decimal values, only whole integers.

You can use `/execute`'s coordinates to modify the origin relative to the target, but you will have to adjust the `dx/dy/dz` values yourself to a proper whole number that fits your needs:

```
/execute @a[score_rightClick_min=1,score_spellActive.fire_min=1,lm=5] ~4.5 ~0.25 ~-4.5 scoreboard players set @e[dx=-8,dy=-1,dz=8,team=!Players] target.fire 1
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working. I have it set up the same way you did in the example but it doesn't seem to register anything in the area.

Comment: **Update**: It does work, but it seems like you can't use decimals in the directions specifier when you are specifying for an entity.

Comment: This worked for the first part, but doesn't seem to work for the second part.